# What is the intended use of memoir's \setbinding{}?

Tags: margins, memoir

In section 2.4 of the memoir manual, the `\setbinding{⟨length⟩}` command is discussed:

> In some cases, for example when doing a Japanese stab binding, it may be desireable to add a small allowance to the spine margin for the binding. You can use the command `\setbinding` for this purpose. It decreases the effective page width by `⟨length⟩` and later this length will be added on to the spine margin, thus restoring the page width to its original value. If you use `\setbinding` than it must be *after* setting the page width and *before* setting the spine and fore-edge margins.

I do not understand why I would use this command, instead of just making the spine margin wider when setting up my margins. Can anyone explain a situation where it's the better approach?

Comment: I'm too old and can't remember. You can use any method you like for setting margins. How about trying using `\setbinding` and whatever method you like and see what, if any difference, there is in the result. In the end use whatever works best for you.

Comment: I do remember that I found it useful in at least one of my documents which is why I added it to the class over 20 years ago.

Comment: If the user is reading instructions provided by a printing service, the instructions might refer to the binding allowance, rather than the spine margin. This is because the printing service expects that the user is creating the file via a word processor, rather than via TeX.